# Plotting a point

Tags: c#, plot

I have code which will draw a graph that scales if the user attempts to resize the form(by dragging the form's corners). The form will get an x and y co-ordinate in a textbox. When a button is pushed, i want to plot the point which they have indicated. However, the Click event contains the parameters Object Sender and EventArgs e. The OnPaint method (which i am overriding in order to draw the graph) has the parameter PaintEventArgs.

Due to this, when the button is clicked i cannot do the following code:

```
g.DrawString("♫", new Font("Calibri", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.HotPink), (PlotArea.X + (7 - xMin)* PlotArea.Width/(xMax - xMin)), (PlotArea.Bottom - (6 - yMin) * PlotArea.Height / (yMax - yMin)));
```

This is because "g" is of type PaintEventArgs. How do i get around this so that in the onClick method i can plot the co-ordinate?

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PlotIt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List<TheList> GraphPoints = new List<TheList>();

        //Define the drawing area
        private Rectangle PlotArea;
        //Unit defined in world coordinate system:
        private float xMin = 0f;
        private float xMax = 10f;
        private float yMin = 0f;
        private float yMax = 10f;
        //Define the offset in pixel:
        private int offset = 150;
        Graphics g;

        Boolean buttonPressed = false; 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.White;

        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g = e.Graphics;

            //Calculate the location and size of the drawing area
            //within which we want to draw the graphics:
            Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;

            PlotArea = new Rectangle(rect.Location, rect.Size);
            PlotArea.Inflate(-offset, -offset);

            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, PlotArea);

            Pen aPen = new Pen(Color.Green, 3);
            g.DrawLine(aPen, Point2D(new PointF(5, 0)), Point2D(new PointF(5, 10)));
            g.DrawLine(aPen, Point2D(new PointF(0, 5)), Point2D(new PointF(10, 5)));

            aPen.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();


        }



        private PointF Point2D(PointF ptf)
        {
            PointF aPoint = new PointF();

            aPoint.X = PlotArea.X + (ptf.X - xMin) * PlotArea.Width / (xMax - xMin);

            aPoint.Y = PlotArea.Bottom - (ptf.Y - yMin) * PlotArea.Height / (yMax - yMin);

            return aPoint;
        }



        private void btnPlotGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            g.DrawString("♫", new Font("Calibri", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.HotPink),    (PlotArea.X + (7 - xMin)* PlotArea.Width/(xMax - xMin)), (PlotArea.Bottom - (6 - yMin) * PlotArea.Height / (yMax - yMin)));
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [Control.CreateGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) Method. That should allow you to get the [Graphic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) object you need.

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawString("♫", new Font("Calibri", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.HotPink), (PlotArea.X + (7 - xMin)* PlotArea.Width/(xMax - xMin)), (PlotArea.Bottom - (6 - yMin) * PlotArea.Height / (yMax - yMin)));
g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hmmm... this would be trying to reference a parameter being passed in though i think. Since the click event does not pass in a PaintEventArgs (rather an EventArgs) i don't think it will work.... Thanks though.

Comment: What parameter are you specifically talking about? Because it looks like the only thing you are using out of the PaintEventArg's is the Form's Graphics Object.

Comment: That's correct. However if you look at the method "btnPlotGraph_Click" it does not take the parameter "PaintEventArgs." btnPlotGraph_Click is a method generated by WinForms (when you drop a button on the form - it does not come with the option of passing the parameter PaintEventArgs).

Comment: You are only using the Form's Graphic's object out of the PaintEventArgs. What I suggested is just another way of getting the same Graphics object. There should be no difference.

Comment: Sorry, i think i may be misunderstanding. the key word "this" is used to grab a parameter being passed into a method - correct? I want to use PaintEventArgs within a method that does NOT have that parameter. Using the keyword "this" within a method that does not have PaintEventArgs passed into it won't work. Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class. So in your case it refers to the instance of Form1. This is the same instance that is firing the OnPaint Event.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more appropriate way to do this.

In your`Click` event, you should store the coordinates, and then call `this.Invalidate()`.

This will cause your form to redraw itself, firing the `Paint` event.

It is also possible to create a graphics object manually, but it is a better practice to ask the form to refresh itself by calling `Invalidate`.

Comment: Thanks. This helped quite a bit